# How to generate incremental unique id on MySQL with existing values?

Tags: mysql, unique, generator

I have a table with data which has 3 rows:

[image]

"id" is primary key and auto increment.
order_no is NOT unique index because there may be many company_ids with the same order_no.

I can generate and show user next order_no with this query:

```
select LPAD(count(order_no)+1, 4, '0')  from customers_orders where company_id=28
```

which gives me "0004". It's OK. But the user can also enter id manually and the data is like this somethimes:

[image]

Now it doesn't start with 0001 and the generate query gives me "0003". But I already have "0003" in there. The query should return like "0005".

If I get the latest order_no and add it 1 (for example max(order_no)+1), it won't work. Because the data can be also like this:

[image]

If the data is like this; the query have to generate "0003".

I think I can make this with while loop in PHP, but i want to do this with MySQL if it is possible. Thank you.

Comment: How about using this query? select LPAD(max(cast(order_no as int))+1, 4, '0')  from customers_orders where company_id=28

Comment: It dosn't work but this seems to be right:
select LPAD(max(cast(order_no as UNSIGNED))+1, 4, '0') from customers_orders where company_id=28

don't understand why int isn't working.